# How to accept ssh host verification in jenkins ssh agent

Tags: jenkins, ssh-agent

Refer to following jenkins pipeline script

```
sshagent(['sshuser']) {
    sh "git clone ssh://git@git.local.com/test/test-commit.git"         
}
```

I am always getting following logs in jenkins

```
Cloning into 'test-commit'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Tried a few tricks to auto accept the host verification but all failed, very frustrated.

Comment: how did you solve the issue? did you use the answer below and bypass the check?

Answer (score 4):

If your main concern is with git you could use the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable. It allows you to inject ssh options:

```
stage('My git stage') {
    environment {
        GIT_SSH_COMMAND = "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
    }
    steps {
        sshagent(['sshuser']) {
            sh "git clone ssh://git@git.local.com/test/test-commit.git"         
        }
    }
}
```

Mind you, this comes with some security concerns. You might want to investigate: https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/ssh-host-key-protection

Comment: I tried this solution, however I still got the error defined in the question: `Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue after GitHub changed their RSA key. Some of our jobs were running on master node and used ssh-agent plugin.

Turns out ssh-agent is running in docker container and is storing known hosts in specific format in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` within the container.